# On the existence of solutions for a Fermat-like equation

Tags: number-theory

I was wondering: given $n\ge2$, what is known about the integer $k(n)$ that is the smallest such that the equation
$$a_1^n+\ldots+a_{k(n)}^n=b^n$$
admits a solution with integer, non-zero $a_i$'s and $b$?

Obviously $k(2)=2$, $k(n)\le 2^n$ (else take $a_i=1$ for all $i$ and $b=2$) and, by Fermat's last theorem, $k(n)\ge3$ for $n\ge 3$.

Also, playing around a moment with $3$<sup>rd</sup> powers I found that $k(3)=3$ by the very nice equality
$$3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$$

Are there any more results about $k(n)$?

---

As @DietrichBurde said in a comment, this is realted to the [Euler's sum of powers conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture). In the wikipedia's page you can find the following results for $n=4,5$
$$2682440^4 + 15365639^4 + 18796760^4 = 20615673^4$$
$$27^5+84^5+110^5=144^5$$
and thus $k(4)=k(5)=3$. Furthermore it is stated that it is unknown whether $n$ is a lower bound for $k(n)$, for $n\ge6$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, but it is not the problem I am asking about here, at least not in a way that is obvious to me...

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is more related to Euler's conjecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture. Here is another example for $k(5)=4$: $27^5 + 84^5 + 110^5 + 133^5 = 144^5$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah, that's really nice, thank you. I will add the results of the wiki page to the answer.

Comment: maybe you can ask @Noam D. Elkies

Comment: He did already give a (related) answer at mathoverflow.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Could you link me to it, please? He got a quite long list of answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a collection of links for this question (a bit too long for the comment field). These numbers are studied since Euler in $1769$, who conjectured that for all integers $n$ and $k$ greater than $1$, if the sum of $n$ $k$-th powers of positive integers is itself a $k$-th power, then $n$ is greater than or equal to $k$. There are several discussions on stackexchange, and it might be useful to collect a few links here.

$(1)$ Euler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture.

$(2)$ Growth of the numbers $k(n)$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91375/growth-of-n-nk-for-which-theres-a-non-trivial-solution-to-x-1k-cdotsx-n.

$(3)$ Lower bounds on $k(n)$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64649/lower-bounds-on-the-easier-waring-problem.

$(4)$ A lot of examples: http://euler.free.fr

$(5)$ A collection of such Diophantine equations: https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010.